# Allow shortcodes in product variations description in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product-variations

I would like to use a pods shortcode field inside the woocommerce variable product description but by default the variable description field does not support shortcodes.

The variation description is stored [in an array woocommerce_available_variation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product_Variable.html#300), so I can't simple call the function do_shortcode($variation).

I am trying to allow short codes in this field by using the below code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'shortcode_variation_description');

function shortcode_variation_description( $variation ) {
$variation['variation_description'] = do_shortcode( $variation['variation_description'] );
return $variation;
```

But it's not working. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using your code, it works. To test, I have used the [Woocommerce shortcode `[products]`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-6) in a variation description as follow:

**The imputed text is** *(where **`37`** is a real simple product ID):* 
*"This is a description with a shortcode…  [products ids="37"] As  you can see this shorcode is detected and displayed."*

And I get this display:

[image]

So it works for real. I have lightly made some little changes to this code version *(yours work too)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'variation_description_allow_shortcodes', 10, 3 );
function variation_description_allow_shortcodes( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    $variation_data['variation_description'] = do_shortcode( $variation_data['variation_description'] );

    return $variation_data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot @LoicTheAztec. I implemented your code and now it works just fine! Mega thanks to you - i have been struggling with this issue for hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own shortcode, see the documentation. You can copy/paste the code because it's wrapped in a class so it won't trigger fatal error due to double declaration.

But shortcode do not work that way :

```
function shortcode_handler($atts) {
  //code goes here
 }
add_shortcode("name_of_shortcode","shortcode_handler');
```